# Contagem de ocorrência de um dataframe dando erro

Tags: r

Sou iniciante, sei que meu código ainda está deselegante, mas vamos um passo de cada vez.
Possuo um dataframe com 2 colunas (fonte SO e tipo de doc DT), onde preciso separar por DT as SO, contar as frequências (das SO) e gerar um ranking com as 15+, para cada DT.
Fiz um código olhando os exemplos dados nesse site, conto as frequências e depois separo por tipo de documento, no entanto quando confiro a frequências inicial com a depois da separação a última dá um número sempre inferior. Vou colocar aqui uma pequena amostra.

```
SO                                              DT 
ACM SIGMIS DATABASE                             ARTICLE
ACM SIGPLAN NOTICES                             ARTICLE
MODERN CASTING                                  BOOK
MODERN DEVELOPMENTS IN POWDER METALLURGY        BOOK
ELECTRICAL COMMUNICATION                        CONFERENCE PAPER
ELECTRONIC DESIGN                               CONFERENCE PAPER
ELECTRONIC ENGINEERING (LONDON)                 CONFERENCE PAPER
ELECTRONIC PACKAGING AND PRODUCTION             CONFERENCE PAPER
```

inicialmente meus dados estavam num datafreme

```
q1
q1_so <- data.frame(q1$SO, q1$DT) # pega a coluna SO  e DT e transforma em df
names(q1_so)[1:2] <- c("SO", "DT") # renomeando nome coluna p facilitar
# cria a coluna Freq e conta a frequencia de SO
q1_soma_dt <- data.frame(with(q1_so,table(DT)))

q1_freq <- with(q1_so,table(SO,DT)) 
q1_freq <- data.frame(q1_freq) # quantidade de SO por classe DT
```

## corte para article

```
q1_art <- subset(q1_freq,DT =='ARTICLE' & Freq >0) 
library(plyr)
q1_art <-arrange(q1_art,desc(Freq)) # ordena em ordem decrescente
sum(q1_art$Freq)
```

## rank 20+

```
q1_art <- q1_art[1:20, ]
```

Obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: Resolvi com o result Obrigada Rui

Answer (score 3):

Esta solução usa o pacote `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  group_by(DT, SO) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  slice(1:15)
## A tibble: 8 x 3
## Groups:   DT [3]
#  DT               SO                                       count
#  <chr>            <chr>                                    <int>
#1 ARTICLE          ACM SIGMIS DATABASE                          1
#2 ARTICLE          ACM SIGPLAN NOTICES                          1
#3 BOOK             MODERN CASTING                               1
#4 BOOK             MODERN DEVELOPMENTS IN POWDER METALLURGY     1
#5 CONFERENCE PAPER ELECTRICAL COMMUNICATION                     1
#6 CONFERENCE PAPER ELECTRONIC DESIGN                            1
#7 CONFERENCE PAPER ELECTRONIC ENGINEERING (LONDON)              1
#8 CONFERENCE PAPER ELECTRONIC PACKAGING AND PRODUCTION          1
```

**Dados em formato `dput`.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(SO = c("ACM SIGMIS DATABASE", 
"ACM SIGPLAN NOTICES", "MODERN CASTING", 
"MODERN DEVELOPMENTS IN POWDER METALLURGY", 
"ELECTRICAL COMMUNICATION", "ELECTRONIC DESIGN", 
"ELECTRONIC ENGINEERING (LONDON)", 
"ELECTRONIC PACKAGING AND PRODUCTION"), 
DT = c("ARTICLE", "ARTICLE", "BOOK", "BOOK", 
"CONFERENCE PAPER", "CONFERENCE PAPER", 
"CONFERENCE PAPER", "CONFERENCE PAPER")), 
row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Obrigada. Consigo visualizar a resposta para as 10 primeiras linhas, mas minha menor amostra tem ARTICLE 662,  ARTICLE 162, BOOK 8, CONFERENCE PAPER, 542,...com posso salvar essa informação ?

Comment: Achei que o problema tinha sido resolvido, mas só funciona para uma amostra pequena, não consigo visualizar o resultado.
Para uma amostra grande, usando:
library(dplyr)
q1_so %>%
  group_by(DT, SO) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  head(20)
  
 Eu vejo as 5 primeiras respostas das categorias até chegar em 20 linhas, depois elas são cortadas
 Aumentando o head(50) ele corta em 10 linhas, e não consigo ver o resultado das 8 categorias

Comment: Tentei usar o result = q1_so, para salvar o resultado, no entanto ele mostra o dataframe q1_so original sem as alteraçoes. Esse é o retorno que tenho,    
# A tibble: 21 x 3
# Groups:   DT [8]
   DT               SO                                count
   <fct>            <fct>                             <int>
 1 ARTICLE          ACM SIGPL               17
 2 ARTICLE          METAL POW            16
 3 ARTICLE          IBM TECHNIETIN    15
 4 "ARTICLE "       JOURNAL O              17
 5 "ARTICLE "       DATAMATIO               8
 6 "ARTICLE "       JOURNAL ONT         6

Comment: 7 BOOK             NA                                3
 8 BOOK             HUM-COMPU               2
 9 BOOK             AI, GRAPHIC                1
10 CONFERENCE PAPER NA 
# ... with 11 more rows